# Pydrake: Differential Inverse Kinematics Controller Used on Robot Interacting with Floating Objects - model as arg?

Tags: python, drake

{EDITED: Code Added}
| drake 1.9.0 | python 3.7 | OS: ubuntu 20.04 | pycharm |

I have a Kuka arm welded to world that is knocking around primitive bodies that are not welded to a frame (cubes, cylinders, etc.)

I currently use the Differential Inverse Kinematics Controller for commanding my robot's Cartesian trajectories but this system is failing when I add collision bodies to my plant due to dimensional mismatches (see error pasted below).

It appears my dimensional mismatch is due to the additional collision bodies being floating, and thus the DIKI is requesting a complete state of my plant which includes more than just the arm I want to control.

```
# Build the base diagram & add models: 
builder = DiagramBuilder() 
collision_plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.001) 
robot_resource = FindResourceOrThrow( 
    "drake/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/sdf/iiwa14_polytope_collision.sdf") 
parser_collision = Parser(collision_plant, scene_graph) 
robot_model = parser_collision.AddModelFromFile(robot_resource) 

 

# Add IK friendly plant and models:  
robot_ik_plant = MultibodyPlant(time_step=0.001) 
robot_ik_parser = Parser(robot_ik_plant) 
robot_ik_model = robot_ik_parser.AddModelFromFile(robot_resource) 
 
robot_ik_plant.WeldFrames(robot_ik_plant.world_frame(), robot_ik_plant.get_body( 
        robot_ik_plant.GetBodyIndices(robot_ik_model)[0]).body_frame()) 
robot_ik_plant.Finalize() 
 
if args.add_box: 

    obj_file =  FindResourceOrThrow( 
    'drake/examples/manipulation_station/models/061_foam_brick.sdf') 
    box1 = collision_parser.AddModelFromFile(obj_file, "box1”) 

    box2 = collision_parser.AddModelFromFile(obj_file, "box2”) 
 
collision_plant.WeldFrames(collision_plant.world_frame(), collision_plant.get_body( 
        collision_plant.GetBodyIndices(robot_model)[0]).body_frame()) 
collision_plant.Finalize() 

# make joint state controller: (in separate script)  

joint_space_builder = DiagramBuilder() 

controller = joint_space_builder.AddNamedSystem(“Inverse Dynamics Controller”, InverseDynamicsController(robot_ik_plant,kp,ki,kd,ref_accel) 
joint_space_builder.ExportInput(controller.get_input_port_desired_state(), DESIRED_SYSTEM_STATE) 
joint_space_builder.ExportInput(controller.get_input_port_estimated_state(), CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE) 
joint_space_builder.ExportOutput(controller.get_output_port(), ACTUATION_COMMAND) 
joint_space_diagram = joint_space_builder.Build() 

#make task space controller: (in separate script) 

diki_builder = DiagramBuilder() 

diki = diki_builder.AddNamedSystem('DIKI Controller', DifferentialInverseKinematicsIntegrator( 
    collision_plant, tool_frame, simulation_time_step, diki_parameters)) 
diki_builder.ExportInput(diki.GetInputPort('X_WE_desired'), DESIRED_EE_POSE) 
diki_builder.ExportInput(self.diki.GetInputPort('robot_state'), CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE) 
 
diki_derivative = diki_builder.AddNamedSystem('discrete_derivative', DiscreteDerivative( 
    n_dof, simulation_time_step, suppress_initial_transient=True)) 
 
desired_system_state = diki_builder.AddNamedSystem('multiplexer', Multiplexer([n_dof, n_dof])) 
diki_builder.ExportOutput(desired_system_state.get_output_port(), DESIRED_SYSTEM_STATE) 
 
# Connect the DIKI Output to the Torque Controller's Input for Desired State 
diki_builder.Connect(diki.get_output_port(), diki_derivative.get_input_port()) 
 
diki_builder.Connect(diki_derivative.get_output_port(), desired_system_state.get_input_port(1)) 
diki_builder.Connect(diki.get_output_port(), desired_system_state.get_input_port(0)) 
 
body_input_port = builder.AddNamedSystem("body_poses_passthrough", PassThrough(Value[List[RigidTransform]]())) 
diki_builder.ExportInput(body_input_port.get_input_port(), BODY_POSES) 
 
desired_ee_velocity = diki_builder.AddNamedSystem("desired_ee_vel_passthrough", PassThrough([0] * 6)) 
diki_builder.ExportInput(desired_ee_velocity.get_input_port(), DESIRED_EE_VELOCITY) 
diki_diagram = diki_builder.Build() 
 

# Make the required connections 

builder.Connect(joint_space_diagram.GetOutputPort(DESIRED_SYSTEM_STATE), joint_space_diagram.GetInputPort(DESIRED_SYSTEM_STATE)) 
builder.Connect(collision_plant.get_body_poses_output_port(), joint_space_diagram.GetInputPort(BODY_POSES)) 
builder.Connect(collision_plant.get_state_output_port(robot_model), state_extractor.GetInputPort(CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE)) 
builder.Connect(state_extractor.GetOutputPort(CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE), 
                joint_space_diagram.GetInputPort(CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE)) 
builder.Connect(state_extractor.GetOutputPort(CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE), 
                diki_diagram.GetInputPort(CURRENT_SYSTEM_STATE)) 
builder.Connect(joint_space_diagram.GetOutputPort(ACTUATION_COMMAND), collision_plant.get_actuation_input_port(robot_model)) 
builder.Connect(traj_system.GetOutputPort(DESIRED_EE_VELOCITY), diki_diagram.GetInputPort(DESIRED_EE_VELOCITY)) 
builder.Connect(traj_system.GetOutputPort(DESIRED_EE_POSE), diki_diagram.GetInputPort(DESIRED_EE_POSE)) 

# Create the default context & finalize components 

context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext() 

# finalize all sub-diagrams 
diki_context = diki.GetMyContextFromRoot(context) 
diki.get_mutable_parameters().set_nominal_joint_position(start_pose) 
diki.SetPositions(diki_context, start_pose) 

# Repeat the below lines for any extra collision object  

box1_base = collision_plant.GetBodyByName(base_link, box1) 
collision_context = collision_plant.GetMyContextFromRoot(base_context)   
collision_plant.SetFreeBodyPose(collision_context, box1_base, starting_pose) 
 
# Set positions 

collision_plant.SetPositions(collision_plant.GetMyContextFromRoot( 
    root_sim_context), robot_model, start_pose.flatten()) 

# Initialize the simulator 
simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0) 

simulator.Initialize() 
 
while meshcat.GetButtonClicks(stop_sim_button) < 1: 
    # Advance the simulation 
    t = simulator.get_context().get_time()
```

When I run this, I get a dimensional mismatch at the DIKI:

```
RuntimeError: DiagramBuilder::Connect: Mismatched vector sizes while connecting output port joint_positions of System DIKI Controller (size 21) to input port u of System discrete_derivative (size 7)
```

(This says “size 14” if I only add one box to my plant. Each additional box that is floating has 7DOF: 3 pose,4 orientation. These DOF aren’t actuated, which is why this same framework works with a different controller (JPIC) with the collision_plant as input that leverages the robot_model ModelInstance to recognize the actual number of actuated DOFS.)

Would adding plant model as an argument to this class circumvent this problem? Most other controllers leverage the models for this purpose and the only class that is comparable that I have seen model is not used as an argument for is the raw IK solver.

If model cannot be added as an arg due to the same reasons as the IK solver, what is a recommended architecture to deal with this?

Comment: Cool question, but pretty much impossible to answer without more details. Can you add a minimized code example to illustrate the problem?